# Get value from Tkinter Entry field to another python file

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinter.py

```
entry = tk.Entry(labelframe3, bd = 3)
entry.pack()
entry.place(x = 50, y = 10, width = 220, height = 30)

btn1= tk.Button(labelframe3, text = 'Forecast', command= predict)
btn1.pack()
btn1.place(x = 300, y = 10, width=150, height=30)

def predict():
    value = str(entry.get())
```

main.py

```
modelname=value

X = df['months'].values 
Y = df[modelname].values
```

I need that value from entry file to main.py file in variable modelname to continue program according to user input.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really shouldn't name your file a library name such as `tkinter`.

Comment: `entry.get` returns `str` already.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to sections of an actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
def predict():
    value = str(entry.get())
```

with:

```
def predict():
    return entry.get()
```

and then you should call it like this:

```
import myGUI

modelname = myGUI.predict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your GUI file is named `my_gui` call lines below from the main file:

```
import my_gui
modelname = myGUI.entry.get()
```

This needs to be called *after* the user is given a chance to fill the `entry`.

---

Ideally, the GUI should be the one that drives the script underneath. As in:

my_main.py:

```
#my_main
def create_dfs(modelname):
    global X, Y
    X = df['months'].values 
    Y = df[modelname].values
```

my_gui.py

```
#my_gui
#...
import my_main

def button_callback():
    global entry
    my_main.create_dfs(entry.get())

btn1 = tk.Button(labelframe3, text='Forecast', command=button_callback)
btn1.pack()
```

Comment: Sir, Im getting this error :- Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: @AnupShrestha That is not helpful, the information is that you're getting an error only.